# How to parse Json to HTML from api rather than console

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, json, parsing

I'm trying to take the results that this API returns and have it print to a simple HTML element so that it's readable by a user. Currently it's setup to return all values to the console log. So far I have tried creating a div element in the HTML and printing the data there, I've also tried using innerHTML but I haven't had success with that method either.

```
 <body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <br />
        <input id="myfiles" type="file" multiple="multiple" />
        <button type="button">OK</button>

        <button id="MyButton" type="button" onclick="sendIdentification()">OK</button>
    </div>

    <div id="displayresult"> 
        <p>Result here</p>
        
    </div>
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">function sendIdentification() {
        alert('start');
        const files = [...document.querySelector('input[type=file]').files];


        const promises = files.map((file) => {
            return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                const reader = new FileReader();
                reader.onload = (event) => {
                    const res = event.target.result;
                    console.log(res);
                    resolve(res);
                }
                reader.readAsDataURL(file)
            })
        })

        Promise.all(promises).then((base64files) => {
            console.log(base64files)

            const data = {
                api_key: "Die8ewFGvpw5JrRTuOEjgGR10uLjMwirF3jYaalmRjk4dzP8Gm",
                images: base64files,
                modifiers: ["crops_fast", "similar_images"],
                plant_language: "en",
                plant_details: ["common_names",
                    "url",
                    "name_authority",
                    "wiki_description",
                    "taxonomy",
                    "synonyms"]
            };

            fetch('https://api.plant.id/v2/identify', {
                method: 'POST',
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                },
                body: JSON.stringify(data),
            })

                .then(response => response.json())
                .then(data => {
                    console.log('Success:', data);
                })
                .catch((error) => {
                    console.error('Error:', error);
                });
        })
/* attempt to try parsing to an html element in addition to the console log. Currently throws an error.
document.querySelector('#displayresult').innerHTML = jsonData[1].common_names);
for (var i = 0; i < jsonData.length; i++) {
    document.querySelectorAll('.displayresult')[i].innerHTML = jsonData[i].common_names;
    */
}

                
    };</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

the code you wrote try to add the data to the div before the promise resolves.
instead you should wrote the same code but in the `then` part like so.

```js
 fetch('https://api.plant.id/v2/identify', {
                method: 'POST',
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                },
                body: JSON.stringify(data),
            })

                .then(response => response.json())
                .then(jsonData => {
                    console.log('Success:', jsonData);
                    document.querySelector('#displayresult').innerHTML = jsonData[1].common_names;
                    for (var i = 0; i < jsonData.length; i++) {
                        document.querySelectorAll('.displayresult')[i].innerHTML = jsonData[i].common_names;
                    }
                })
                .catch((error) => {
                    console.error('Error:', error);
                });
```

Comment: Hello, thanks for the response, I tried this however I'm getting an          
    "Error: TypeError: Cannot read property 'common_names' of undefined
    at PlantAi:192". I changed the "jsonData" to just "data" because that seems to be how the api was built and Jsondata was throwing a different error. Also of note the console does say "success", so it is going to the console.

Comment: no the returend json from the api is the parameter passed to the second `then`

Comment: the first errors happens most probably because that the jsonData is not an array
so can you provide the format of the data consoled !

Comment: The initial console displays {id: 10304382, custom_id: null, meta_data: {…}, uploaded_datetime: 1614556267.301842, finished_datetime: 1614556268.300537, …}

Comment: suggestions: Array(5)
0: {id: 76752408, plant_name: "Rosa", plant_details: {…}, probability: 0.6802025919692216, confirmed: false, …}
1: {id: 76752409, plant_name: "Rosa chinensis", plant_details: {…}, probability: 0.1527320943113081, confirmed: false, …}
2: {id: 76752410, plant_name: "Rosa rugosa", plant_details: {…}, probability: 0.02929257583542776, confirmed: false, …}
3: {id: 76752411, plant_name: "Impatiens walleriana", plant_details: {…}, probability: 0.014303056370904305, confirmed: false, …}
length: 4

Comment: so there is no `common_names` that what cause the error message

Comment: From my understanding the common_names is apart of plant_details: that is stored within the "const: data".

Comment: so you have to access it like this `jsonData[i].plant_details.common_names`

Comment: Sorry I'm still getting the same error - I've attached what I wrote so you can see if I'm doing it wrong or not.         document.querySelector('#displayresult').innerHTML = jsonData[1].plant_details.common_names;
                        for (var i = 0; i < jsonData.length; i++) {
                            document.querySelectorAll('.displayresult')[i].innerHTML = jsonData[i].plant_details.common_names;
                        }